# Symbolicating Swift Package Manager builds

Tags: xcode, macos, swift-package-manager, dsym

`Swift Package Manager` can be a convenient way to build swift projects, and, if you ([remove the absolute toolchain @rpath it adds to your binary](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/2d2b3876c78d69b867434da879c6bfa2e22014a9/Sources/Xcodeproj/pbxproj.swift#L464)), you can even distribute its builds.

But SPM doesn't seem to produce `.dSYM` debug symbol packages, so how can you symbolicate the crash reports?

Is there a better way than using `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and then getting Xcode to create the build and `dSYM`s, effectively reducing SPM to `.xcodeproj` shorthand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**
`swift build -c release` seems to create a `dSYM` package by default. But if you suddenly decided you wanted your debug build to have `dSYM`s too, then read on.

You can get `dSYM` output from SPM's `swift build`, by passing `-g` and `-debug-info-format=dwarf` to `swiftc`. To do this from `swift build` the arguments must each be escaped with `-Xswiftc`:

```
swift build -Xswiftc -g -Xswiftc -debug-info-format=dwarf
```

I wasn't thrilled about using Xcode to build because it turns all sub-packages into dynamically linked frameworks which felt like too big a change/yak-shave just to get a readable backtrace.